# How to move files from windows into kali linux app

Tags: kali-linux, windows, virtual-machine

I want to move my openvpn setup from my computer into the kali linux that i downloaded from microsoft store. can people tell me how to do that?

I only have terminal installed so there is no GUI, so i want to move the config file from my windows to the linux terminal

Thanks a lot.

J.

Comment: How familiar are you with Linux-based systems?

Comment: I'm voting to close this "question".

Comment: @roaima pretty well but i dont know how to access the directory of my virtual machine (only terminal) from my windows OS.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov didnt know you get a vote

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: "_i dont know how to access the directory of my virtual machine"_ - Depending on the virtual machine layer you may have direct access to the filesystem. Alternatively, `scp` or `sftp` can work

Answer (score 1):

In Kali, install the `openvpn` with the following command:

```
sudo apt install openvpn
```

see https://www.kali.org/tools/openvpn